# How should I authorize calls to an API behind an Apache reverse proxy behind CAS authentication?

Tags: apache-2.4, docker, reverse-proxy, authentication

Apologies if this is incoherent. I'm very new.

I have an Apache server protected by CAS in a Docker container. I'm using [mod_auth_cas](https://github.com/apereo/mod_auth_cas) to do this. I have an API running on a different container which is accessed through a reverse proxy using ProxyPass so that the user must be authorized to make API calls. I now want to know the UID in my API so that I can make sure that the user has permissions.

I'm hoping that there's a way to add an additional parameter with the verified UID to incoming API calls. I feel like there should be some way to do this with mod_rewrite, but I'm not sure how. I suppose I'd have to get the UID as a string.

Comment: If the only access to the back-end API is through the CAS proxy, and you only need the user ID to authorize the user, you might do better to do the authorization within CAS. Then the API doesn't have to know or care who the user is.

Comment: The API has to care about who the user is because of our really granular permissions for everything. Eventually, I figured out how to set the X-Remote-User header when forwarding the request. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33368653/how-do-i-set-remote-user-in-a-http-header

Comment: That's good. You should post it as an answer. It's fine to answer your own question, and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting the X-Remote-User http header in the redirect.

```
RequestHeader unset "X-Forwarded-User"
RequestHeader set X-REMOTE_USER "%{REMOTE_USER}e" env=REMOTE_USER
```

The `REMOTE_USER` environment variable is set by `mod_auth_cas`.